# Get Openshift cluster compliance data (Critical and Warning) from portal using OCM in golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, openshift

Can we get the openshift cluster compliance data from the openshift portal using OCM in golang. Does it have a GetComplianceReports or GetComplianceStatus function that can fetch the data.

`reports, err := client.GetComplianceReports(context.Background(), clusterID)`
The following is giving error - > type *ocm.Client has no field or method GetComplianceReports

Or is it better trying the client-go library ?